# bash: jar: command not found

Tags: java, bash, jenkins

I'm using ***Jenkins*** to deploy the build.

We need to extract files from a **.war** into some directory.
We have an **.xml** file which includes commands to extract the files from the **.war** file and start the server.

The build is being created properly but the **.war** extraction is not happening and the destination folder is being left empty.  The Jenkins Console shows the following output:

```
[sshexec] bash: jar: command not found
```

As read from other answers, I have set the `PATH` properly in **.bashrc** or in **.profile** but I'm still facing the same issue.

Comment: Are you sure you have a JDK installed and not a JRE?

Comment: @fge : JDK is Installed (jdk1.6.0_33) and JRE is present inside JDK folder, private jre

Comment: If you don't have the `jar` command on your system, there is no "properly" way to fix the `PATH`.  If it does exist on your system, you have not set the `PATH` "properly".  I didn't want to remove this sentence when editing your question, but you should probably clarify which you mean, or perhaps just take it out.

Answer (score 44):

Install Java devel as follows:

```
 yum install java-devel
```

Comment: On Debian that would be `apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk` or one of the [alternatives](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=bin%2Fjar&mode=path&suite=stable&arch=amd64).  See also https://wiki.debian.org/JavaPackage

Answer (score 7):

To be specific, `JAVA` bin directory is not in your `PATH` variable. Add it to `PATH` variable. In order to search the executables, the OS need to have a list of directories to look up. So, Add the directory which contains 'jar`tool in the`PATH` environment variable

Note : For Windows, Path separator is (`;`) and for Unix-like OS, Path separator is (`:`)

Comment: Bin Directory is Present and this is How i configured .. Is that Ryt ?                                                                                                                                 **export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_33
                                                               export PATH=$PATH:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_33/bin
CLASSPATH=$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar:$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/rt.jar;export CLASSPATH**

Comment: Are you able to execute in this way - `/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_33/bin/jar` in terminal. Did that work?

Comment: Actually,, i m using **jar -xvf filename.war** to extract the Files,, The Command Works Fine if it is Invoked Manually,, but using Jenkins It is Not.. Is it some kind of Permission Issue ??

Comment: Do you have `JAVA_HOME` set? Is it set properly in your user profile?

Comment: Yes.. As mentioned above **JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_33**

Comment: ok, Do you get any errors? How are you running jenkins? Did you open jenkins and configure JDK in manage jenkins? Please read this [link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Jenkins/article.html)

Comment: We have totally 15 Jobs running on 5 different Servers .. In 4 servers the Extraction is Proper. Only with One Server , It is giving error as **[sshexec] bash: jar: command not found**.

Answer (score 5):

The "[sshexec]" tells me you are using some Jenkins plugin to execute a command on a remote host.

This usually means Jenkins executes this (or an equivalent thing by implementing the SSH protocol natively):

```
ssh user@remotehost 'jar arg1 arg2...'
```

What happens here is the sshd daemon on the remote host will execute the default shell of the user and ask the shell to execute the command line. The shell is typically not executed as a "login shell", meaning the shell will skip the initialization steps that login shells normally do when the user logs in interactively.

You can study `man (name of your shell)` to see exactly what the difference is between a shell executed with `-l` option and one executed without it. In the case of bash it essentially means `.profile` and `.bashrc` will not be executed, so any PATH modifications you might have there will not take place.

I think your best bet is to provide the full path to the `jar` command when you want to execute it.

Comment: Yes. After using complete path for jar it is working (In jenkins). Thank you for saving my time.

Answer (score 1):

As you are executing the command on remote host so, it will invoke the new Shell on the remote host. The PATH which you have set in the current host .bashrc file will not make any difference. Instead if you set the PATH for Java in remote host's .bashrc things should work else if you are running any script then mention the complete path for JAR like /usr/jdk64/jdk1.8.0_40/bin/jar -tf /tmp/jars/abc.jar while invoking the command on remote host.

Two ways to do:

1. export PATH=$PATH:/usr/jdk64/jdk1.8.0_40/bin ---> in remote host's .bashrc
2. /usr/jdk64/jdk1.8.0_40/bin/jar -tf /tmp/jars/abc.jar --> invoke the jar command with complete path for JAR from remote host.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 22.04:

```
apt-get install openjdk-19-jdk
```