# mvn command not found in jenkins scripted pipeline

Tags: jenkins

I am new to jenkins. I am getting the below error when i am trying to trigger scripted pipeline through jenkins.

> /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/pipelinedemo@tmp/durable-a4f2db2a/script.sh:
>   line 1: mvn: command not found

Below is the code snippet .

```
pipeline {
    agent any 
    stages {
        stage('clone repo and clean it ') { 
            steps {
                sh "rm -rf my-app"
                sh "git clone https://github.com/Testing/my-app"
                sh "mvn clean -f my-app"
            }
        }
        stage('Test') { 
            steps {
                 sh "mvn test -f my-app" 
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy') { 
            steps {
                 sh "mvn package -f my-app"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that i am able to run mvn command through freestyle project. i am getting this error from scripted line. Please answer this. thanks in advance. Geeth

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't run Jenkins Build - bundle: "command not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10365792/cant-run-jenkins-build-bundle-command-not-found)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/23538864/545127

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/47320994/545127

Comment: Make sure Maven path is added to $PATH environment variable on the server where your job is running.

Answer (score -1):

ssh to your linux server, then
1. Install maven on your linux machine.
2. Add it to your PATH variable. (you should able to run `mvn -version` command there)
3. Restart your jenkins service.

Then, you should be able to use it in your pipeline script.